# JSNI - invoking native method from another native method

Tags: gwt, jsni

How to call another native on button click of a native method? can we call more than 1 native method from single native method on button click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do it.

Sample code:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    exportSayHello();

    Button btn = new Button("Click");
    btn.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            buttonClicked("vartika");
        }
    });

    RootPanel.get().add(btn);
}

public static native void exportSayHello() /*-{
    $wnd.sayHelloFunction = $entry(@com.gwt.test.client.GWTTestProject::sayHello(Ljava/lang/String;));
}-*/;

public static native void buttonClicked(String value)/*-{
    $wnd.sayHelloFunction(value);
}-*/;

public static native void sayHello(String value)/*-{
    $wnd.alert("Hello " + value);
}-*/;
```

Steps to follow:

- Export method `sayHello()` to JavaScript using `JSNI`
- Now call it from native method `buttonClicked()` using the same name `sayHelloFunction` that is exported to `JavaScript`.

Read more about [GWT JSNI](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html).